# Solving or estimating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(-a/(x^2+b))}{x^2+c}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

Can the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(-a/(x^2+b))}{x^2+c}dx$$
be made explicit ($a,b,c>0$)? I'm also asking those of you who have access to CAS which can solve it.
In case it can't, is there a very good upper bound? I need a better one than the obvious bound
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+c}dx = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{c}}$$
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where did this integral appear? The case $b=c$ is doable via the substitution $x\to \sqrt b\tan(x/2)$.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(-a/(x^2+b))}{x^2+b}dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt b} e^{-\frac{a}{2b}}I_0\left(\frac{a}{2b}\right)$$
Where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. I'm not too optimistic about the case where $b\neq c$.

Comment: @Zacky Thank you for your help. The integral appeared as estimate of a Fourier coefficient of a multidimensional periodic function. What I was trying to estimate the Fourier coefficients in order to estimate the actual function. After posting this question and after further working on the problem I realized that the answer of this question here would not solve my actual problem since I estimated even before too much. But since people seem to be intersted in my question I let it here (or should I better delete it?).

Comment: @Zacky. Do you think possible to compute $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\Big[ -\frac{k}{t^2+1}\Big] }{(1+t^2)^{n+1} }$$ with $k >0$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici well, there is: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\Big[ -\frac{k}{t^2+1}\Big] }{1+t^2}dt=\pi e^{-\frac{k}{2}}I_0\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)$. So we just need to take $n$ derivatives with respect to $k$ in order to compute that integral.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\Big[ -\frac{k}{t^2+1}\Big] }{(1+t^2)^{n+1} }dt=(-1)^n\pi\frac{d^n}{dk^n}\left(e^{-\frac{k}{2}}I_0\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)\right)$$
Putting it into a nicer form might not be that easy. Perhaps here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule can help though.

Comment: @Zacky. My idea was to write $c=b+\epsilon$ and use series. Anyway, thanks for your answer. Cheers -:-)

Comment: @Zacky Actually in my case always $b<c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a}{x^2+b}}}{x^2+c}~dx&=2\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a}{x^2+b}}}{x^2+c}~dx
\\&=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a}{b\tan^2x+b}}}{b\tan^2x+c}~d(\sqrt b\tan x)
\\&=2\sqrt b\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a}{b\sec^2x}}\sec^2x}{b\sec^2x+c-b}~dx
\\&=2\sqrt b\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a\cos^2x}{b}}}{b+(c-b)\cos^2x}~dx
\\&=2\sqrt b\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^n\cos^{2n}x}{b^n(b+(c-b)\cos^2x)}~dx\end{align}$$